# Total Map in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a total in TypeScript to model a state-machine. The idea was to implement a total map from all states to all states, as follows.

I am getting an error in my `CanFoo` function:

```
error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Here is the code:

```
type HumanState = 'stand' | 'walk' | 'run';

interface Transition<T> {
  stand: T
  walk: T
  run: T
};

interface TransitionMap {
  stand: Transition<boolean>
  walk: Transition<boolean>
  run: Transition<boolean>
}

let Foo: TransitionMap = {
    stand: {
      stand: true,
      walk: true,
      run: false,
    },
    walk: {
      stand: true,
      walk: true,
      run: true,
    },
    run: {
      stand: false,
      walk: true,
      run: true,
    }
};

let CanFoo = (from: HumanState, to: HumanState): boolean => {
  // error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
  return Foo[from][to];
}
```

Is there a better way to implement a total-map, or is there a way to get to typecheck correctly? Or is there a neater way to define the type? (Like `Map<HumanState, Map<HumanState, boolean>`?)

Comment: Seems like we should talk about the syntax error on line 4 first

Comment: That's odd - the syntax error was not showing up in VS Code until I did a full rebuild. Will edit.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh - thanks - I've fixed up the code now. I was trying a few different ways to implement this and VSCode got confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly declare the index in these cases:

```
type HumanState = 'stand' | 'walk' | 'run';

interface Transition<T> {
    stand: T
    walk: T
    run: T
    [index: string]: T
};

interface TransitionMap {
    stand: Transition<boolean>
    walk: Transition<boolean>
    run: Transition<boolean>
    [index: string]: Transition<boolean>
}

let Foo: TransitionMap = {
    stand: {
        stand: true,
        walk: true,
        run: false,
    },
    walk: {
        stand: true,
        walk: true,
        run: true,
    },
    run: {
        stand: false,
        walk: true,
        run: true,
    }
};

let CanFoo = (from: HumanState, to: HumanState): boolean => {
    return Foo[from][to];
}
```

Problem is that the type of `Foo[from]` is not known to the compiler. It could be anything as objects can have attributes of different types. The compiler option "noImplicitAny" generates an error every time you don't specify the type for yourself and it's inferred type is `any`. This is a good thing but in these particular cases you have a little bit of extra work.

When you explicitly declare the index operator you tell the compiler which type to expect. You could also explicitly declare `any`. This would also make the error go away as the `any` is not inferred (i.e. not implicit) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A second possibility would be to use the [Map type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object. When you do so, you can use the methods of `Map` which may be handy depending on what else you are doing with your total map. On the other hand constructing such a map is a bit cumbersome:

```
type HumanState = 'stand' | 'walk' | 'run';

let createMap = (values: Object): Map<any, any> => {
    let result = new Map();
    for (let key in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (values[key] instanceof Object)
                result.set(key, createMap(values[key]));
            else {
                result.set(key, values[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let Foo: Map<HumanState, Map<HumanState, boolean>> = createMap({
    stand: {
        stand: true,
        walk: true,
        run: false,
    },
    walk: {
        stand: true,
        walk: true,
        run: true,
    },
    run: {
        stand: false,
        walk: true,
        run: true,
    }
});

let CanFoo = (from: HumanState, to: HumanState): boolean => {
    return Foo.get(from).get(to);
}
```